# Query tablesorter when deleting/moving table rows

Tags: tablesorter

I am using tablesorter on one of two tables on a page.

The user can move rows between the tables. When I sort on the table after moving a row from one table to the other, the row jumps back to the original table.

I had this working correctly with version 2.0.5b of tablesorter by adding a `$('#sortTable').trigger('update')` command as part of the `droppable.drop` event. However, this has stopped working in version 2.25.3 of tablesorter.

What do I need to do differently to get this working again?

Answer (score 0):

I got it to recognize the row change by adding a setTimeout before calling $('#sortTable').trigger('update').  I am hoping there is a better solution than that.

```
setTimeout(function () {
    $('#sortTable').trigger('update');
}, 400);
```